# The smallest subalgebra $R[M]$ that contains a subset $M$ of a $R$ algebra $A$

Tags: abstract-algebra

$R$ is a commutative ring with $1$

I face difficulties to understand a theorem that the above described set is equal to the set below:

[image: smallest subalgebra]

The translation for the German part is

Let $A$ be a  $R$ algebra and $M\subseteq A$ a subset

Only finitely many $r_{\alpha}\neq 0$

What I don't understand is what the parameter $\alpha$ means. Do they mean a finite subset of $M$ ? Is a multiplication of same elements allowed? I.e. if $x\in M $ is also $1xxxx$ in the set for example?

Comment: In the end it amounts to taking finite sums yes, but it's just an index. In principle, there are infinitely many $\alpha$.

Comment: Specifically, this is [multi-index notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-index_notation). Though instead of the indices being used for powers, the entries are regarded themselves as indices into $M$.

Comment: One then could also write instead of just $\alpha$, $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @New2Math The length of $\alpha$ may vary, also $M$ might be uncountable.

Comment: Essentially what it is saying is take all finite sums of products of some element of $R$ with a finite product of things in $M$ (allowing repeats). Also you shouldn't think of $\alpha$ as a set, not just because we allow repeats, but also because $A$ might not be commutative, so the order of multiplication might matter.